# Add element to array if it exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have a nested Object

```js
    payload={
    abc:"abc",
    something:[
       somevalue:"somevalue",
       nestedAray:[
          {
              anotherValue:"anotherValue"
          }, 
          {
              optionalValue:"optionalValue",
              optionalValue1:"optionalValue1"
          }
       ]
    ]}
```

here optionalValue1 key is optional in the payload. Need map the same object to the new new object with different Key names

expected output:

```
{
    name:"abc",
    skills:[Java:"somevalue","JSLibrary":[{JavaScript:"anotherValue"},{Angular:"optionalValue",NodeJs:"optionalValue1"}]]
    }
```

I mapped the payload as

```
let output={};
for(i=o;i<payload.something.length;i++){

for(j=o;j<payload.something.nestedAray.length;j++){
skill[j]={
Angular:"payload.something[i].nestedAray[j].anotherValue"
NodeJs:"payload.something[i].nestedAray[j].anotherValue1" // this is optional should add only if exist to same array
}
}
}
output={Java:payload.something,skills:skill}
```

How to check for the optional parameter in the nested object

Comment: maybe before doing the operation you can check if the given object as a given property name using [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). If you need a more general approach you could recursively visit the object going deeper only if the property value is an object and for each one check if it includes such propety name or not.

Comment: There is no JSON involved in this question, so I've edited that word out. You have objects, plain old JavaScript objects, POJOs if you want, but JSON is a text format for transporting data, not another word for "objects without all the bits that are harder to talk about".

Answer (score 0):

**You can just use :**

```
if (data.something.nestedAray[i].optionalValue1) {
      skill.NodeJs = data.something.nestedAray[i].optionalValue1;
}
```

**to check if the option value 1 is existing in your array already.
Refer the working code sample below :**

```js
let correctedData = {
  abc: "abc",
  something: {
    somevalue: "somevalue",
    nestedAray: [
      { anotherValue: "anotherValue" },
      { optionalValue: "optionalValue", optionalValue1: "optionalValue1" },
    ],
  },
};

function checkForOptionValue1(data){
  let skills = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < data.something.nestedAray.length; i++) {
    let skill = {};
    skill.JavaScript = data.something.nestedAray[i].anotherValue;
    if (data.something.nestedAray[i].optionalValue1) {
      skill.NodeJs = data.something.nestedAray[i].optionalValue1;
    }

    skills.push(skill);
  }
  return { Java: data.something.somevalue, skills: skills };
}


console.log(checkForOptionValue1(correctedData));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Your skill keys need to be assigned to certain values in `payload` object, I resigned from for loop and directly assigned the values based on position in array. Moreover, I made sure not to add an empty object into array, if the optionalValue1 don't exist.

```js
const payload = {
  abc: "abc",
  something: {
    somevalue: "somevalue",
    nestedAray: [
      { anotherValue: "anotherValue" },
      { optionalValue: "optionalValue",optionalValue1:"optionalValue1" },
    ],
  },
};
let skills = {
  Java: '',
  JSLibrary: []
};
function formatData(data){
  let something = data.something;
  let nestedArray = something.nestedAray;
  skills['Java'] = something.somevalue;
  const javascript = nestedArray[0].anotherValue;
  const angular = nestedArray[1].optionalValue;
  const nodeJs = nestedArray[1].optionalValue1;
  skills.JSLibrary = [{Javascript: javascript}, {Angular: angular,  ...(nodeJs && {NodeJs: nodeJs})}];
}
formatData(payload);
console.log(skills);
```